# Is it possible to change the timestamp of a dataframe that I'm referencing?

Tags: python, finance, quantitative-finance

I have the current dataframe of 7 different assets:

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

end = dt.datetime.today()
start = end - dt.timedelta(3650)

tickers = ["SBUX", "MCD", "CMG", "WEN", "DPZ", "YUM", "DENN"]
bench = ['SPY', 'IWM', 'DIA']

table_1 = pd.DataFrame(index=tickers)
data = yf.download(tickers+bench, start, end)['Adj Close']
data.head()
```

As you can see, it's trailing 10 years. I've already done what I needed to do with this dataframe (found volatility, daily returns, etc). However, I want to manipulate it again, this time with trailing 3 months. My question is, how can I reference this data without constantly making a new data object? This is what comes after:

```
end = dt.datetime.today()
start = end - dt.timedelta(90)
data2 = yf.download(tickers+bench, start, end)['Adj Close']

log_returns = np.log(data2/data2.shift())
log_returns.head().dropna()
```

I don't want to constantly be doing "data2", "data3", "data4" etc everytime I need a new time period, as it makes the code look messy. Is there a simple code that allows me to change the timestamp of the dataframe I'm referencing?

Comment: If you have 10 years of data, don't you have 90 days in the same data set?

Comment: Yep. I'm just wondering if there's another way to change the time period without affecting the work I've already done.

Comment: if you have 10 years then you could `copy` some data into new `dataframe` and then you not affect original data. something like `data_90 = data[ data["date"] > start ]`.  Eventually it may need `.copy()` at the end. If you want to change values then you have to create new `Dataframe` (new `data`) - you can't change values and still have original values at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

As you got a datetime index already, you can download the full dataset once and then use `loc[start:end]` to slice your DataFrame to the desired data ranges. There is no need to download the data multiple times or to create multiple variables.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import datetime as dt

end = dt.datetime.today()
start = end - dt.timedelta(3650)

tickers = ["SBUX", "MCD", "CMG", "WEN", "DPZ", "YUM", "DENN"]
bench = ['SPY', 'IWM', 'DIA']

data = yf.download(tickers+bench, start, end)['Adj Close']

# calculate log returns
log_returns = np.log(data/data.shift())
log_returns.dropna(inplace=True)


# slice to desired range
slice_end = dt.datetime.today()
slice_start = end - dt.timedelta(90)

df_slice = log_returns.loc[slice_start:slice_end]

# repeat with other dates
df_slice = ...
```